# Removing duplicates in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, failure-slice

I'm fairly new to prolog and I'm currently reading through a book which is giving me practice examples to code. It has tasked me with removing duplicates.

Note: I have read other stackoverflows, and I understand how to remove duplicates but what I don't understand is why my code isn't working. ( I have chose a different approach to other stackoverflows)

I've created a is_member predicate which I believe works fine.

```
is_member(X, [Head,Tail]):-
    X == Head;
    is_member(X, Tail).
```

And then my remove_duplicates predicate

```
remove_duplicates([Head|Tail], Without):-
    is_member(Head, Tail),
    remove_duplicates(Tail, Without);
    remove_duplicates(Tail, Head).
```

In my head this makes sense, it checks if the Head is a member of the tail and if it is, it doesn't add it to the Without list,

else it does.

I'm obviously missing something trivial here,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's simplify the task a bit by first considering `is_member/2`.

You write it as:

```
is_member(X, [Head,Tail]):-
    X == Head;
    is_member(X, Tail).
```

Consider how easy it is to misread this as:

```
is_member(X, [Head,Tail]):-
    X == Head,
    is_member(X, Tail).
```

**Exercise**: What did I change?

For this reason, I recommend a layout like the following:

```
is_member(X, [Head,Tail]):-
        (   X == Head
        ;   is_member(X, Tail)
        ).
```

Now, on to a few **test cases**!

First, it is always a good idea to post the **most general query**. This simply asks: *Are there any solutions at all?*

```
?- is_member(E, Ls).
nontermination
```

That's *not* a good sign!

So, let us try a few **concrete** cases. For example, *is `a` a member of the empty list*?

```
?- is_member(a, []).
false.
```

That's *good*! It is what we expected.

Then, is `a` a member of the list `[a]`?

```
?- is_member(a, [a]).
false.
```

That's definitely **wrong**!

I recommend you start from there, and then move on to more complex definitions. Approach it in a systematic way:

1. Write down what **ought to hold**.
2. Try the **most general query** to see if you can obtain answers from your program.
3. Try **concrete test cases**.
4. Think about what the predicate actually **means**: You can use a predicate in multiple directions, and in many of these cases, the way you described the predicate does not make sense. For example, both the list and the element can already be **given**, and in that case there is nothing to "add" or "remove".

To locate causes of unexpected failure in your program, use [program-slicing](/questions/tagged/program-slicing), for example by using the following definition to **generalize away** goals:

> ```
> :- op(950,fy, *).
> *_.
> ```

You can now write:

```
is_member(X, [Head,Tail]):-
        (   * X == Head
        ;   * is_member(X, Tail)
        ).
```

which is a **massive generalization** of your original program, and in fact declaratively equivalent to:

```
is_member(X, [Head,Tail]) :- true.
```

The test case above **still fails** with this fragment, which shows that the program is still **too specific**:

```
?- is_member(a, [a]).
false.
```

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you I will take your advice on board

Comment: Also I believe, I fixed the error. With: `is_member(X, [Head|_]):-
   X == Head.
`

Comment: This fixes the concrete test case `is_member(a, [a])`, yes. However, try the *slight* **generalization** of the test case: `?- is_member(a, [X]).` This still **fails**. Overall, I can only recommend to **avoid** non-monotonic predicates like `(==)/2`. They can only be used safely in very particular situations, and yield **wrong** answers in more general cases. To express that two terms are **equal**, use `(=)/2`. It works correctly in *all* directions.

Comment: shouldn't is_member(a, [X]). fail?

Comment: Think it through: Suppose `is_member(a, [X])` *fails*. Then this would mean, if we read it declaratively, that **there are no solutions whatsoever** for this query. However, we have already established that `X = a` **is** a solution, because `is_member(a, [a])` **must succeed**! Therefore, since the more **specific** case `is_member(a, [a])` succeeds, the more **general** case `is_mumber(a, [X])` definitely **must not fail**. Otherwise, it would mean that the program reports wrong answers.

Comment: I've done some more reading and i've found = is better than ==

Comment: The best method is to keep everything that is possible to **pattern matching**: You do not need either of these predicates (neither `(=)/2` *nor* `(==)/2`) in this case, because you can write: `member_list(E, [E|_]).` as a simple fact that is true: `E` is a member of every list that has the form `[E|_]`. This simply expresses what is true and works in all directions, for *generating*, *testing*, etc.